# Image doesn't update in database (mongoid + devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I'm trying to update a profile photo in my user model. I have associated the devise to this model, and trying to perform this update with the default form provided in devise view.

I already made necessary changes to devise accept the new fields:

```
  # application_controller.rb
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name, :profile_photo])
  end
```

Here is the line I added to my user model:

```
mount_uploader :profile_photo, PictureUploader
```

Here is my uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [250, 250]
  end

  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

Here is the form that I'm using:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),
             html: { method: :put, class: "form-horizontal",
             multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: resource %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
              Profile photo</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= render "formfield_profile_photo", object: f %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
              Profile informations</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="field form-group">
                <%= f.label :name, class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field form-group">
                <%= f.label :email, class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
              Password</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="field form-group">
                <%= f.label :new_password, class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                    <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="field form-group">
                <%= f.label :new_password_confirmation, class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr></hr>

      <div class="form-inline text-center">
        <em>Please, provide your password to confirm the changes.</em>
        <br></br>
        <div class=" form-group">
          <%= f.label :current_password %>
          <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
            <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The formfield_profile_photo partial, called in my form:

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <%= object.label :current_profile_photo %>
      <div class="form-group ">
        <%= image_tag(current_user.profile_photo.url(:thumb), alt: current_user.name, id: "profile_photo") %>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-left">
    <%= object.label :profile_photo do %>
      <span id="img_select" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Select new photo</span>
    <% end %>
    <div class="text-center">
      <%= object.file_field :profile_photo, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png', name: 'file_upload' %>
      <div id='file-info'>
      </div>
      <img id="preview" src ="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added `name` and `profile_photo` to devise parameters. But if I try to update both, only the name is updated. Here is the log of this action:

```
Started PUT "/users" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-10-02 18:04:21 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"beRkN3JPVQAJ+cuP8NxlfD8VbjqrGz6E65LYGVAhJan64yhpPj9+bwXfXPV0wSckqpU33nxA4IyqnrcueO00qg==", "file_upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f231d42da50 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161002-17514-czo6xs.jpg>, @original_filename="images.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_upload\"; filename=\"images.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "user"=>{"name"=>"new test", "email"=>"test@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57f14baf0640fd446aad07fa')}, "limit"=>-1, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000674365s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57f14baf0640fd446aad07fa')}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000476095s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.update | STARTED | {"update"=>"users", "ordered"=>true, "updates"=>[{"q"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57f14baf0640fd446aad07fa')}, "u"=>{"$set"=>{"name"=>"new test", "updated_at"=>2016-10-02 18:04:21 UTC}}, "multi"=>false, "upsert"=>false}]}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | sample_app2_development.update | SUCCEEDED | 0.000505685s
Redirected to http://localhost:2000/
Completed 302 Found in 309ms
```

Someone can explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A wild guess, something like `user.profile_photo.store!` might solve your problem.

Comment: I looked into carrierwave documentation, but I could not figure out: after call `store!`, I steel need call  `save` in my object, right? If yes, `store!` works (testing in my terminal). But I have not figured out how to add that to Devise controller (because according the log, I understand that the problem is there).